# Postgres LIKE with column value as substring

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to compose a WHERE statement that will match rows where a column value is a substring of another string.

For example, I might have an `event` record with a `name` field of `Edward Sharpe`. I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE(name LIKE 'Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes');
```

This doesn't work. I've also various permutations of:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE('%' || name || '%' LIKE 'Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes');
```

Which also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you considered [regexp_matches](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)?

Comment: Is it `select 'Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes' like '%' || name || '%' from (select 'Edward Sharpe'::text "name") foo`?

Comment: @mlt No, that query makes no sense. As you've written it there, it will return a single unnamed column with the value `true`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @mlt But what's with the extra sub-query, and not mentioning any actual table? It's a valid query, but not very similar to what was asked for.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your second attempt is painfully close to correct. The [**`LIKE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) keyword takes a *string* on its left, and a *pattern* on its right. Both can be expressions, but `%` only has a special meaning in the pattern to the right.

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM events
 WHERE name LIKE '%Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes%';
```

Or rather this:

```
 SELECT * FROM events 
 WHERE 'Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes' LIKE '%' || name || '%';
```

Also note that all string operations in Postgres are case sensitive by default. To match a pattern ignoring case, use `ILIKE` in place of `LIKE`.

Comment: Your second example did it. Apparently the wildcard-ed value has to come after the LIKE statement. Thank you!!

Comment: I just tweaked my answer because WHERE doesn't need any brackets for a simple case like this. They won't hurt, just a waste of keystrokes.

Comment: Some typos. And the first query is off target AFAICT.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Feel free to edit for typos, I'm on a mobile, so positioning accurately is tricky. I gave both queries to stress that the %s can go onto either value, as long as they're on the right of the LIKE

Comment: @Erwin Oh, I'm amused you edited to say LIKE is an operator: I wrote that initially, but wasn't sure, because operators have such a specific meaning in Postgres... :)

Comment: Well, strictly speaking you are right. The actual *operator* behind the scenes is `~~` or `~~*` for `ILIKE`. So I switched back to "keyword". Careful, btw, the otherwise equivalent operator `~~` is ranked differently in operator precedence. You would have to use parentheses: `... ~~ ('%' || name || '%')`.