# Sequelize LIKE/iLIKE with column value as substring

Tags: sequelize.js

There was an earlier question on this for Postgres itself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441319/postgres-like-with-column-value-as-substring)

What I am trying to get at is how to write the following in Sequelize using operators:

```
SELECT * FROM events 
 WHERE 'Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes' LIKE '%' || name || '%';
```

- events is the table
- name is the column value (e.g. Edward Sharpe)

It is essentially the reverse of

```
name: {
   [Op.iLike]: "%" + "Edward Sharpe and the Magnetic Zeroes" + "%",
}
```

Comment: The answers given are good valued ones. Please remember to choose the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the custom query like so? i am not sure where you are getting your data from but if it was say graphql it would come to me in the args like so but that might be irrelevant to you...

```
const { string, column } = args;
const result = models.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM events
 WHERE :string LIKE '%' || :column || '%';`,
            {
              replacements: {
                string, column
              },
              type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
            });
```

I'm not sure i understand the benefit of trying to produce that with operators, when the custom query functionality is readily available to you... i highly doubt sequelize is capable of forming that query for you on it's own regardless of how you set it up with Ops....

Comment: Is the syntax `'%' || :column || '%'` specific to sequelize? I have never seen the `||` in a ILIKE search

Answer (score 0):

I also consider it unlikely that sequelize will handle your sequence (string_literal like column_plus_wildcard).  This specific example could be handled using INSTR, like so:

```
Events.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(
              Sequelize.fn('INSTR',
                 Sequelize.col('name'),'Edward Sharpe'),
              {$gt : 0}
           )
   })
```

Other situations, such as %Edward%Sharp%Magnetic%, a regular expression function could be useful.